# Who do the other names on the list of idols in episode 2 refer to?

Tags: hacka-doll

In episode 2, the producer has a list of idols/groups scheduled for events, and pens the Hacka Dolls into one of the slots to fill space.

[image]

I suspect that all of these are references to other idols or idol-like entities. Going down the list:

- まつだひじりこ "Matsuda Hijiriko" → [Matsuda Seiko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seiko_Matsuda) (kanji pun on 聖)
- "u's" → [μ's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love_Live!)
- "Sit Down Girls!" → [Wake Up, Girls!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake_Up,_Girls!)
- 美少女ハリウッド "Bishoujo Hollywood" → [Shounen Hollywood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sh%C5%8Dnen_Hollywood)
- **でんじは組,etc "Denji wa Kumi, etc" → ???**
- ミス・カラフール "Miss Colorful" → [Miss Monochrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miss_Monochrome)
- スーパーソニ男 "Super Soni-o" → [Super Sonico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Sonico)
- (Hacka Doll)
- 珂那ちゃん "Kana-chan" → [the fleet's idol, Naka-chan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OcB8SaORxBA)
- **ワン子クラブ "Wanko Club" → ???**
- **長森明菜 "Nagamori Akina" → ???**
- ゆりかおる "YuriKaoru" → [YuiKaori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YuiKaori)
- **Square → ???**

I haven't managed to figure out the referents of the four ones I've bolded above. Who all are being referred to here?

Comment: Isn't 明栞, Akari?

Comment: @ʇosɥıuonʞʎonʞo I honestly have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some likely culprits:

- でんじは組 →
  [でんぱ組.inc](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%A7%E3%82%93%E3%81%B1%E7%B5%84.inc), Denpagumi.inc
- ワン子クラブ →
  [おニャン子クラブ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%8A%E3%83%8B%E3%83%A3%E3%83%B3%E5%AD%90%E3%82%AF%E3%83%A9%E3%83%96), Onyanko Club
- <s>長森明栞 →
  [佐保明梨](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BD%90%E4%BF%9D%E6%98%8E%E6%A2%A8), Saho Akari
  (Unsure), maybe
  [長森佳容](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%95%B7%E6%A3%AE%E4%BD%B3%E5%AE%B9), Nagamori Yoshiro,
  too</s>
- 長森明菜 → [中森明菜](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akina_Nakamori), Akina Nakamori (singer) <sub>Credit to @Passed</sub>
- Square → [Circle](http://www.kpopsfan.com/home/circle/ciecle2.htm) (Unsure)

Comment: It is not 長森明栞, but 長森明菜 ==> 中森明菜

Comment: @Passed Good catch - that makes a lot more sense, and explains why I couldn't find any good readings for 「明栞」. The Square → Circle thing seems fairly convincing, too, so I'm going to go ahead and accept this answer. (I only _just_ got the 電磁波/電波 joke. Doh!)